# Why isn't the image rendering in Material-UI's CardMedia?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to fit an image in CardMedia. Here's the code:

```
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image="../public/assets/bnha.jpg"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography className={classes.title}>
            Vigilante: Boku no Hero Academia Illegals Chapter 97
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Mar 13, 2021
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
```

I can't figure out why the image won't render. Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: you need to import the image

because the webpack build process looks for img in different path

Comment: You have to put the image file in an accessible public web folder, not in the node/webpack developpement folder. Than access to it with ./images/bnha.jpg

Comment: Upload the image to the public web folder, for asp.net core - in `wwwroot`, not sure what you use for your backend. Then either a: do an `import` of the specific image and load it in OR use an absolute path